# Swift "Cannot invoke '-=' with argument list of type '(@lvalue CGFloat, $T7)'

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting this error message when I try to run this code:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

sprite.xScale = 0.5
sprite.yScale = 0.5
sprite.position = location

self.addChild(sprite)

var dt: Float = 1.0/60.0

sprite.position.x -= 100.0*dt;
```

The error message appears on the last line by the way

Comment: I had the same problem with a += that turned out I was simply referencing the wrong variable in a very large playground file. This question was spot on to point me in the right direction to where I slipped up.

Answer (score 4):

you need to change `dt` to `CGFloat` because `sprite.position.x` have type of `CGFloat`

```
var dt: CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
```

in Swift, arithmetic operators require both operands have same type